# What does a sport pilot have to do to get a private pilot certificate in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training, pilot-certification

What are the minimum requirements for obtaining a privates pilot certificate if a pilot  already has a sport pilot certificate?

The requirements for a private pilot certificate don't changes because you already have a sport pilot license. However by successfully obtaining a Sport Pilot certificate, you should have already completed some of the private pilot requirements.

- How much of your sport pilot training counts towards your private
  pilot license?
- How much of the training will have to be re-done?
- Does it depend on
  the type of your flight instructor's certificate?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you hold a Sport Pilot certificate and are looking to upgrade it to a Private Pilot certificate, your best bet is to use the requirements of [Part 61 Subpart E](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61). All of the flight time you logged earning a Sport Pilot certificate applies towards Private, but additional hours and types of flight time need to be logged.  The training you received in the same category and class (eg Airplane, Single Engine) [applies](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/part-61#p-61.109(l)) per `§61.109(l)` because you hold a Sport Pilot certificate.

The requirements for each are paraphrased below. You'd have to log the difference, which is a minimum of **20 hours**, including another 5 hours of dual and 5 hours of solo. There's a lot more to it than what I reference below, but this is the basics.

*How much of the training will have to be re-done?* This should vary wildly from pilot to pilot. You'll need to redo training as required to meet standards. If you're transitioning right away, theoretically none, but it's likely that some retraining will be required.

*Does it depend on the type of your flight instructor's certificate?* Yes, in concert with your accomplishment level.  If the instructor has only a CFI-S (Sport) certificate, none of the dual instruction hours are able to be counted for the private pilot dual hours criteria unless you have your Sport Pilot certificate. If the instructor had a CFI-A (Airplane) certificate, the dual hours earned for your sport pilot certificate will also count toward the dual hour requirements of the private pilot certificate.

See the [Kern INK Interpretation](http://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/agc/pol_adjudication/agc200/interpretations/data/interps/2009/kern%20ink%20-%20(2009)%20legal%20interpretation.pdf)

**Required for Sport** ([citation](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.2&idno=14#14:2.0.1.1.2.10.1.7))

- 20 hours of flight time, including at least:
- 15 hours of flight training from an authorized instructor and at least:
- 5 hours of solo flight training in the areas of operation listed in `§61.311`

**Required for Private** ([citation](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&rgn=div5&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.2&idno=14#14:2.0.1.1.2.5.1.5))

- 40 hours of flight time that includes at least:
- 20 hours of flight training from an authorized instructor and:
- 10 hours of solo flight training in the areas of operation listed in `§61.107(b)(1)`

If you've chosen a flight school that operates a Part 141 program, you get to do it all over. Hooray!

Comment: That's a very nice and to-the-point answer. According to what I know (actually according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Pilot_License)), a Private Certificate (Part 141) can be obtained in as little as 35 hours.

Comment: Thanks! And yes, that's correct, but then the sport pilot's time will not apply towards the requirements of 141, which is an approved predetermined course.

Comment: This answer has one problem for those not familiar with the terminology (and thus those likely to seek answers in this question). _If your instructor is a CFI, they can provide you with the training required for a Private Pilot certificate._ -- that's correct but some people may not know there's a difference between a CFI and a CFIS. A CFIS is _only_ able to provide instruction towards the sport pilot certificate, while a CFI can provide both... so it depends on the rating of your previous instructor(s) at the time of instruction.

Comment: @mah is correct and this answer should be updated to reflect that.  If the instructor only holds a sport pilot instructor certificate, none of those hours count towards the 20 hours of dual required for the private pilots license.  If the instructor is a CFI-A then all of the hours will directly transfer to the dual requirements of the private pilot license.

Comment: Just saw the updates. Thanks, mah and @wbeard52.

Comment: I don’t understand the CFIS paragraph.  I thought CFIS dual hours *never* counted towards a Private, only CFIA dual hours, but that’s not what your answer says.

Answer (score 5):

I am a CFI CFII MEI with over 8000 hours dual given and direct experience in this area of confusion.  Just to clarify everything above into what is and isn't.  It comes down to they type of instructor you received your sport pilot training from.

If they are the traditional CFI your minimum of 20 hours of dual that you did with them counts.  If they were a Light Sport rated CFI none of your dual will count.

Another big concern is if you do your private pilot training part 61 or 141.  Part 61 would be the least expensive way to go since you get credit for your 20 (+) hours of dual you flew with a normal CFI.  However, under Part 141 you are signing up for an FAA approved curriculum and you have to fly the whole program and NO PREVIOUS training regardless of type of instructor can be carried over.  This is consistent with any type of 141 program regardless if it is IFR, Commercial, Multi, etc., now previous experience logged can be counted towards a Part 141 program.

The honest truth about 141 being a savings only really applies when you start from one rating and go right to the next, any time spent flying above the minimums from the previous rating or  between ratings can be applied to the next.  However there are now 141 programs out there that let you work on a combined certification where you are working on your private and IFR at the same time, this has the potential to be a real money saver for the career focused student, or even someone who is not career bound but is committed to having an Instrument rating for safety or more reliable travel.

Answer (score 4):

To add a few things to egid’s answer, there are a few specific areas besides just the overall hours requirement that are not required for a sport pilot, therefore may not have been included in the training. A sport pilot would need to check their training logbooks to see if the hours meet the specific requirements below.

## 1) Cross-country dual and solo hours

- PPL requires 3 hours of dual cross-country; SPL only requires 2 hours.
- PPL requires 5 hours of solo cross-country; SPL has no specific requirement for this, only 5 hours *total* solo.

## 2) Cross-country solo distances

The cross country solo flight requirements are also different. PPL requires

> §61.109 (a)(5)(ii) One solo cross country flight of **150 nautical miles total distance**, with full-stop **landings at three points**, and one segment of the flight consisting of a **straight-line distance of more than 50 nautical miles** between the takeoff and landing locations*

Whereas SPL is only 75nm total, two legs and one leg of over 25nm.

## 3) Solo landings

PPL requires

> §61.109 (a)(5)(iii) Three takeoffs and three landings to a full stop (with each landing involving a flight in the traffic pattern) at an airport **with an operating control tower**.*

SPL doesn’t specify a number of solo landings except for in the cross-country flight. Note the tower requirement. There are no tower requirements for SPL unless you have a controlled airspace endorsement.

## 4) Night flying

Sport pilots are not allowed to fly at night, so it was probably not included in training. Private pilot requires

> §61.109 (a)(2) 3 hours of night flight training in a single-engine airplane that includes—
>
> > (i) One cross-country flight of over 100 nautical miles total distance; and
> >
> > (ii) 10 takeoffs and 10 landings to a full stop (with each landing involving a flight in the traffic pattern) at an airport.

## 5) Instrument flight

Instrument training is not required for sport pilots. Private pilot requires

> §61.109 (a)(3) 3 hours of flight training in a single-engine airplane on the control and maneuvering of an airplane solely by reference to instruments, including straight and level flight, constant airspeed climbs and descents, turns to a heading, recovery from unusual flight attitudes, radio communications, and the use of navigation systems/facilities and radar services appropriate to instrument flight

## 6) Written test

You must also take the PPL written exam which is different from the SPL exam.

## 7) Practical test

The practical test requires 3 hours of test prep with a CFI. These have to be performed within 2 months of the test, so they will have to be redone.

---

* All emphasis mine.

Comment: @StephenS the accepted answer says that CFI-S doesn't count `unless you have your Sport Pilot certificate`. So that means if you already have your SPL it will be not be a problem, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Meet the requirements listed in §61.103:

To be eligible for a private pilot certificate, a person must:

(a) Be at least 17 years of age for a rating in other than a glider or balloon.

(b) Be at least 16 years of age for a rating in a glider or balloon.

(c) Be able to read, speak, write, and understand the English language. If the applicant is unable to meet one of these requirements due to medical reasons, then the Administrator may place such operating limitations on that applicant’s pilot certificate as are necessary for the safe operation of the aircraft.

(d) Receive a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor who:

(1) Conducted the training or reviewed the person’s home study on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed in §61.105(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought; and

(2) Certified that the person is prepared for the required knowledge test.

(e) Pass the required knowledge test on the aeronautical knowledge areas listed in §61.105(b) of this part.

(f) Receive flight training and a logbook endorsement from an authorized instructor who:

(1) Conducted the training in the areas of operation listed in §61.107(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought; and

(2) Certified that the person is prepared for the required practical test.

(g) Meet the aeronautical experience requirements of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought before applying for the practical test.

(h) Pass a practical test on the areas of operation listed in §61.107(b) of this part that apply to the aircraft rating sought.

(i) Comply with the appropriate sections of this part that apply to the aircraft category and class rating sought.

(j) Hold a U.S. student pilot certificate, sport pilot certificate, or recreational pilot certificate.