# Can hours logged training to be a Sport Pilot apply toward the Private Pilot Certificate?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

Can my training in a Sport aircraft with a Sport instructor be used to fulfill the requirements to become a Private Pilot?

As an example, assume I've started my training to be a Sport Pilot, but decided I'd rather be a Private Pilot.

Comment: Related question: [What does a sport pilot have to do to get a private pilot certificate?](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-does-a-sport-pilot-have-to-do-to-get-a-private-pilot-certificate)

Comment: I've added the faa-regulations tag given that the only answer deals only with the faa.

Answer (score 9):

Absolutely, you can log just about any flight time in an aircraft!

The definition of flight time is in [14 CFR 1.1](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/A16147FC43C4F9B286257A9500451B45?OpenDocument) and says:

> **Flight time** means:
>
> (1) Pilot time that commences when an aircraft moves under its own
>   power for the purpose of flight and ends when the aircraft comes to
>   rest after landing; or
>
> (2) For a glider without self-launch capability, pilot time that
>   commences when the glider is towed for the purpose of flight and ends
>   when the glider comes to rest after landing.

However, the **instruction** logged towards a sport pilot rating by a *flight instructor certificate with a sport pilot rating* ([61.413](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/7F4301528DF1D8DF862576C400578B2B?OpenDocument)) may not be used toward the requirements of the private pilot certificate.

If the instructor is a CFI certified under [61.181](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgFAR.nsf/0/1635CA05BE5D036C86256EE10063A4D5?OpenDocument) then the instruction may also be used towards your private pilot certificate but you will need to be proficient to the higher standards, which may require additional training.

For those who already have their Sport Pilot Certificate, take a look at this question: [What does a sport pilot have to do to get a private pilot certificate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/28/what-does-a-sport-pilot-have-to-do-to-get-a-private-pilot-certificate)

Comment: I think the second half of your answer is the actual answer :) you should emphasize that in the intro instead, since the question is asking "can training hours logged towards Sport Pilot work towards Private Pilot". If the applicant has earned a sport rating... then yes (additional rating experience + addl. rating checkride). Otherwise, no.

Comment: @egid The question has been updated to say that he has not earned a sport rating yet, which is how I originally interpreted the question.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying that if instruction is received from a CFI certified under 61.181, then you can count that instruction as time towards your PPL; whereas if the instructor merely has a "flight instructor certificate with a sport pilot rating", then that instruction time only counts towards your SPL, not your PPL. Is that right?

Comment: @TannerSwett That's correct.