# Is possible to do a private pilot license training and check-ride on a Light Sport Aircraft?

Tags: general-aviation

I am planning to do my Private Pilot License. Is it acceptable to do all my training and Check-ride on a LSA?

Comment: There should be nothing wrong with that, the problem would be if you were trying to get a Sport Pilots license and did your training on a non-LSA, you would have to take your check ride in an LSA aircraft. If nobody comes up with an answer, I'll write one up later but need to look up the regulations that apply.

Comment: Which country/regulations are you asking about?

Comment: Related [Can hours logged training to be a Sport Pilot apply toward the Private Pilot Certificate?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/1477/8730), [What does a sport pilot have to do to get a private pilot certificate in the US?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/28/8730), [Sport pilot upgrade to private pilot](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13815/8730)

Comment: Consider practical aspects to trying to get a Private Pilot's Cettificate on an LSA.
Will the Certificate be restricted to LSA? Can there be dual instruction on the LSA? (This is a requirement on the instructor for a student and instructor). Is the LSA insured for the purpose? There is no restriction on the type of aircraft on which you can earn a Private Certificate - you can do training on a 747 if that is available - but there are basic requirements, like dual flight instruction. No instructor is going to fly with you unless you demonstrate that you have correct insurance coverage.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes. The regulations make no reference to the TYPE of aircraft. Just to the Category and Class. You will need to have at least 3 hours of dual instruction under actual or simulated instrument conditions, flying solely by reference to instruments. As long as this can be done in the particular LSA you are flying, or you achieve it in a different aircraft, it counts.

LSA is neither a Category nor is it a Class of aircraft.

You will have to get a type rating to fly passengers (even not for compensation or hire) if one is required for that aircraft.