# Does LSA hours count towards PPL training hours

Tags: flight-training

I hold a LSA license wit 200 hours. I am currently doing my PPL and I was wondering if any of the SLA hours can count for some of my PPL training hours? What are the regulations?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Could you please specify in which country you are in? the question is otherwise a tad too broad, as one would have to cover all the possible worldwide regulations.

Comment: I am not sure this is a complete duplicate, if it is about a different legislation, it is not.

Comment: If it's FAA then [this](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/28/8730) is pretty much a dupe too